# Getting a value in a .json file using a constant to represent the value's name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, and I have a config file named config.json as follows:

```
{
    "token":"TokenPlaceholder",
    "prefix":"a.",
    "devPrefix":"+."
}
```

In my main index.js file I have this code that gets the prefix type dynamically from a different command file:

```
const commandPrefixType = botClient.commands.get(commandName).prefixType;
```

I require config.json like this:
`const CONFIG = require('./config.json');`

The value of the constant `commandPrefixType` will either be `prefix` or `devPrefix`. How can I use this constant to dynamically get the value of said prefixType from config.json?

For example, if the command's prefixType value is 'devPrefix', then how can I get the value '+.' without using an if/else or switch block? (I want it to be dynamic because I plan on adding more prefixes in the future).

Thanks

Comment: Use indexer -> `CONFIG[commandPrefixType]`

Comment: Thank you, is that specific to only .json files?

Comment: Nope, that's bog standard JavaScript, you can use it on any JS object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution to your problem is to access your object values by using bracket ([]):

```
const CONFIG = require('./config.json');
const commandPrefixType = botClient.commands.get(commandName).prefixType;

// Access to the prefix
const commandPrefix = CONFIG[commandPrefixType];
console.log(commandPrefix)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I found it can also be done (and is easier) like this: `const commandPrefix = CONFIG[botClient.commands.get(commandName).prefixType];`